# How to exclude an element and all children in css with :not()

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to exclude an element from my selector as well as all of its children. But the following command does not work with the universal selector

Example :

```
  body:not(.css3ui):not(.css3ui *):not(.toolsIcon){
        line-height : 1;
        overflow-x : hidden;
  }
```

Comment: The `:not` selectors refer to `body`, rather than its contents

Comment: Please post the html code  and the expected html code result.

Comment: @GalAbra

This is just an example of exclusion

All css selectors must have this exclusion system

Comment: Or another radical solution. Would be to add an "EX-UI" class to all my items and exclude it with:not(.EX-UI)

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple but a little hardcore solution with jquery. add a specific class to all my items

```
$('.css3ui,.css3ui *').addClass('EX-UI');
```

and then exclude it with:not()

```
selector:not(.EX-UI)
```